# .DS_Store Causing Git Issues

Tags: git, macos

I recently made a new branch, committed to it, and switched back to an old branch.

I tried to check out the new branch, but I got this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
client/.DS_Store
```

So, I did some googling, and learned that these should have been in my .gitignore. So I added them to my global .gitignore to prevent having this problem in the future. But that doesn't fix my problem in the present, which is that when I use this command to fix the error as I've seen suggested, it doesn't work, throwing the following error:

```
git rm --cached client/.DS_Store
fatal: pathspec 'client/.DS_Store' did not match any files
```

I really need to switch back to my other branch! How do I do that at this point?

EDIT: My new global .gitignore:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: You could try git add . && git stash, then switch to the other branch. Also, can you copy and paste your gitignore? Any time I add to my gitignore the changes are reflected. I did have to use something similar to your cache removing command above, but I didn't have to specify the folder in question.

Comment: That worked. I was able to switch to the other branch. Thank you!

Comment: no problem - see my answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gitignore for that folder seems to be incorrect.

Try this

```
# OS generated files #
######################
client/.DS_Store
## This one might be better
# **/.DS_Store
```

I believe that should work.

Or you can try

```
git add . && git stash
```

That should get you to the other branch, but you'll probably want to fix up your .gitignore.

Comment: So having a global .gitignore with .DS_Store won't make git ignore .DS_Store files in subfolders of repos?

Comment: @DJG: it will, except that once a file is tracked, it's too late: an ignore entry has no effect. That includes the case when some other idiot (like myself from the past :-) ) accidentally put the file in long ago.

Comment: So now that the file is in, this repo is stuck with it, regardless of any modifications I make to its .gitignore?

Comment: Is .DS_Store a file or a directory? If it's a file, use *.DS_Store - it will want to find the .DS_Store file in the directory of the gitignore file, but not all .DS_Store files (if it is a file). We have a lot of files in a repo that are later ignored.  Your files will always be in master if you've committed them, but you should be able to ignore them from future branches.  The problem is, cloning them or pulling will overwrite your DS_Store (file/dir).  It might be time to make a new repo for this.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. My global .gitignore should prevent problems like this in new repos.

Comment: I just looked it up.  It is a file.  I think **/.DS_Store might be best.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you are stuck with files that stop you from changing branches you can temporarily stash them and then pop them out again, stash is like a little dodgy branch you can use for emergencies, just don't forget not to pop them out of you could bring on more confusion to your git workflow.

Stash only stashes added files so this is what I do.

1. git status (check to see if any files are untracked)
2. git add . (Only if untracked files exist)
3. git stash (hides the files away in the stash branch
4. Now you have a "clean" repo you can change branch and do what you want

You probably want to go to your second branch and then 
git merge branchwithgitignore

One your done u can do:

git stash pop

and everything should just work itself out here.